# Creating registry keys and values with Inno Setup

Tags: windows, registry, inno-setup

I am trying to register the following code in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.
I am a newbie doing this, I need help

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ProgramTell\softell101.exe]
"Language ID"="1033"
"Language"="english"
"Manual"="Manual.pdf"
"ReadMe"="Readme.txt"
"Install Location"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ProgramTell\\prosoftfolder\\Episode 1\\"
"Uninstaller"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ProgramTell\\prosoftfolder\\UNINSTALL_softell101.exe"
"Franchise"="softell101"
"Distribution"="ProgramTell"
"Version"="1.0.0.0"
"SaveSoftFolderName"="Episode 1"
"GE_GUID"="{5BCB9452-D12C-4552-8F73-883C7DBE10EB}"
```

I have tried using the following but it doesn't save:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HKCU` is short for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. If you want `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, use `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` or `HKLM`. If you want to write to 32-bit `HKLM` (aka `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node`), use `HKLM32`. See [documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection).

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM32; Subkey: SOFTWARE\ProgramTell\softell101.exe; ValueType: string; \
  ValueName: Language ID; ValueData: 1033
Root: HKLM32; Subkey: SOFTWARE\ProgramTell\softell101.exe; ValueType: string; \
  ValueName: Language; ValueData: english
Root: HKLM32; Subkey: SOFTWARE\ProgramTell\softell101.exe; ValueType: string; \
  ValueName: Manual; ValueData: Manual.pdf
...
```

Comment: Thanks you so much is working now @Martin Prikryl